# Is there an ethernet header in IEEE 802.11

Tags: sockets

I have been capturing some packets over wifi using wireshark for analysis. If I captured IEEE 802.11 frames on an interface in monitor mode. If I capture an IEEE packet on an open network without encryption then I cannot see any ethernet headers. However if I capture the same packets on a usual interface(not in monitor mode), then I can see ethernet headers. I was not able to decrypt wpa packets captured in monitor mode for more analysis. So is there actually an ethernet layer when an IEEE packet is transmitted? Or is it added to it by the driver before delivering to applications listening on the upper layers?
Here is a packet missing ethernet layer.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ethernet is defined by [IEEE 802.3](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.3-2012.zip), not [IEEE 802.11](http://standards.ieee.org/about/get/802/802.11.html) (Wi-Fi), so, no, there is no ethernet header in 802.11 frames; they are different network types, and IEEE 802.11 has its own frame format and headers. It the same with any of the IEEE 802.x LANs. For instance, IEEE 802.5 (token ring) has a different frame and header format, too.